# Поиск в mongo из nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Какая библиотека nodejs помогает упростить механизм формирования условий фильтрации doc.find(filter{}) по данным из req.body? Для некоторых параметров поиск должен осуществляться по условию like /.*часть слова.*/, а для некоторых по =, или between и т.д.

Comment: А вы попробовали работать с mongoose?

Comment: Я отказался от mongoose в пользу родных библиотек в mongodb.